# Formal justification in changing the order of a summation and an integration

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

If $k > 0$ how can the interchange between the summation and the integration for the following expression be formally justified:

> $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2k \cos x)^{2n}}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} \, dx$$

My thoughts were to apply the following form of [Fullini's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged/83747#83747). It says that for general $f_n$, if $\int \sum |f_n| < \infty$ or $\sum \int |f_n| < \infty$, then $\int \sum f_n = \sum \int f_n$. Applying this result we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left |\frac{(-1)^n (2k \cos x)^{2n}}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} \right | \, dx &< \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(2k)^{2n}}{(2n + 1)\binom{2n}{n}} \, dx\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(2k)^{2n}}{(2n + 1)\binom{2n}{n}}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\arcsin (k)}{k\sqrt{1 - k^2}} < \infty,
\end{align}
where the series expansion used can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507683/evaluation-of-a-series/507735#507735). This result however is only valid for $|k| < 1$ whereas in my case $k > 0$.

Comment: If $k>1$ and $x \simeq 0$ then $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2k \cos x)^{2n}}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}}$ is divergent by the divergence test.

Comment: Let $j=[0,\pi /2]$....If $|k|<1$ then the partial sums $f_n$ in your series are continuous and converge uniformly, so the full sum $f$ is continuous  (so $f$ is integrable), and $|\int_jf -\int_jf_n|=$ $|\int_j(f-f_n)|\le$ $\le \int_j|f-f_n|\le$ $ (\pi /2)\max \{|f(x)-f_n(x)|:x\in j\}\to 0$ by uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f.$